# How to get all array in json object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I have json object send from view to html by success via ajax in django like this:

```
json: Object
name1: Array[2]
name2: Array[2]
age: '18'
class: 'CLS01'
phone: ''
code: 'SV01
```

Now I want to loop in json object and get all array, in this case is `name1` and `name2`. How can I do that?

Comment: could you please make your mind and let us know where do you want to loop? - python code, - django template, - html (with js - any libraries used?)

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for eachdata in data %}
    {% if eachdata == 'name1' or eachdata == 'name2' %}
        {% for eachrec in eachdata %}
          {{ eachrec }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %} 
{% endfor %}
```

This is how you can get the nested array out in django templates

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe (where `obj` is your object):

```
var arrays = [];
for(prop in obj) {
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && Array.isArray(obj[prop])) {
    arrays.push(obj[prop]);
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(arrays, null, 2)); //Your arrays (in the array: arrays)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
for(var x in jsonObject){
   if(jsonObject[x].constructor === Array){
     //do anything
   }
}
```